# jQuery Populate content inside a new element before appending it

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

I'm trying to populate `featured` with data then append it to #wrapper. This isn't working for me. What am i doing wrong?

```
var featured = '<div id="featured"></div>';
$('#imageTable tbody tr td img').each(function(){
    $(featured).append($(this).attr('src'));
});
$(featured).appendTo('#wrapper');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $featured = $('<div id="featured"></div>');
$('#imageTable tbody tr td img').each(function(){
    $featured.append($(this).attr('src')).append('<br />');
});
$featured.appendTo('#wrapper');
```

Explaination:

When you do this inside the loop `$(featured)`, it creates a NEW div for each selected element, so only the last div will be appended to your `#wrapper`. You need to create the jQuery object outside of the `each` loop.

Comment: Haha same answer at the same time. You forgot to unwrap that last `$(featured)` call though

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have the `$(featured)` call inside the loop. You only want to call it once.

Try this:

```
var $featured = $('<div id="featured"></div>');
$('#imageTable tbody tr td img').each(function(){
    $featured.append($(this).attr('src'));
});
$featured.appendTo('#wrapper');
```

Answer (score 1):

Very Similar to Bryan Ross's, just creating the div in a more efficient manner. It may not be as straight forward, but I believe it is more performant.

```
var $f = $('<div>',{id:'featured'});
$('img,#imageTable > td').each(function(i){
    $f.append($(this).attr('src');
})
$f.appendTo('#wrapper');
```